# Login page not appearing - Remix

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I have a login page which has a "Sign in"button. Upon clicking that button, the page redirects to the microsoft login screen. I made some loader changes and now I am unable to see the login page at all. It auto redirects to the microsoft login screen. Can someone enlighten me on whats going on?

This is my code.

```
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
  const user = await authenticator.authenticate("microsoft", request, {
    failureRedirect: "/",
    successRedirect: "/stewardship",
  });

  // Check if the access token is expired
  if (new Date((user as User).expiresAt) < new Date()) {
    const tenantId = process.env.TENANT_ID!;
    // Call token endpoint to get a new access token
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("client_id", process.env.CLIENT_ID!);
    data.append("client_secret", process.env.CLIENT_SECRET!);
    data.append("scope", "openid email profile");
    data.append("refresh_token", (user as User).refreshToken);
    data.append("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
      { method: "POST", body: data },
    );

    const responseData = await response.json();

    // Update the session with the new access token, refresh token, and expiration
    const session = await getSession(request.headers.get("Cookie"));
    session.set("user", {
      ...(user as User),
      accessToken: responseData.access_token,
      refreshToken: responseData.refresh_token,
      expiresAt: new Date(
        Date.now() + responseData.expires_in * 1000,
      ).toISOString(),
    });

    const cookie = await commitSession(session);
    // Return the user with Set-Cookie header
    const headers = { "Set-Cookie": cookie };
    return json(user, { headers });
  }

  return user;
};

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <Form action="/auth/microsoft" method="post">
      <Grid
        container
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
      >
        <Grid item xs="auto">
          <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
            <CardContent>
              <Box textAlign="center">
                <Box component="img" src={Logo} />
                <Box my={2}>
                  <Typography align="center">
                    This site uses your organizational username and password.
                    Sign in with your credentials.
                  </Typography>
                </Box>
                <Box>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    endIcon={<ArrowForward />}
                    sx={{ borderRadius: "30px" }}
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    Sign In
                  </Button>
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Form>
  );
}
```